# Column not found. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to filter my results from two tables: trips and activities that are linked by table trips_activities.
Activity:
[image: Activity]
Trip:

[image: Trip]

Trip_Activity:

[image: Trips_Activities]
Their relations are defined as follow:
In activity model:

```
public function trips()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Trip',"trips_activities","activityid","tripsid");
    }
```

In trip model:

```
public function activities()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Activity',"trips_activities","tripsid","activityid");
    }
```

When i try to run following query:

```
$trips = $trips->whereHas('activities', function($r) use($activities) {
            $r->whereIN('activityid', $activities)->get();
            });
```

It gives following output:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'trips.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `activities` inner join `trips_activities` on `activities`.`id` = `trips_activities`.`activityid` where `trips_activities`.`tripsid` = `trips`.`id` and `activityid` in (2))
```

Comment: share the table structure too

Comment: @Naincy I have added table structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the `get()` function in wrong place. You need add `->get()` after all your query:

```
$trips = $trips->whereHas('activities', function($r) use($activities) {
        $r->whereIN('activityid', $activities);
        })->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Query

```
select * from `activities` 
inner join `trips_activities` on `activities`.`id` = `trips_activities`.`activityid`
where `trips_activities`.`tripsid` = `trips`.`id` and `activityid` in (2)
```

Here trips.id means look for trips table and id column. But I do not see any trips table. I believe it should be `activities.tripsid`

Comment: But the query are generated by laravel itself.